# System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting : Unable to load one or more of the requested types

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm currently trying install a web application on win server 2012. After compiled the app, i'v deployed it in IIS. After the logging page the next page is not displayed and i see the error in the subject in the svclog file. I saw that this error could be caused because a missing dll but as the application run on another server, i compared the dll's in the bin directory and that's the same as on the new server. I'm newbee in web application. I'don't know how to debug it and i can't go further in my task to improve the application. Any help would be appreciate !
The application is silverlight + MVVM + RIA services + sql server

thanks

Comment: More details? You should actually present the exact error messages.

Answer (score 0):

it COULD be due to win server configuration.
Make sure that WCF Services HTTP Activation is installed.

[image]

Errors messages and stack are the bare minimum in diagnosis. It's like symptoms for sickness. 
Even if this would solve your problem, please reports them here, for future reference.